# REGEX: How to find a date format after a specific keyword?

Tags: regex, date, pattern-matching, expresso

I am scratching my head over this. For example I have:

```
Date
sometext
somtext
27-7-2013
```

What I want to do is I want to get the first date format string pattern after the Date keyword. Here is what I currently have:

```
(?i)(?<=date.*)\d+-\d+\d+
```

But unfortunately, I am getting nothing and if I just try to get all the string after the date keyword, e.g.

```
(?i)date.*
```

I am only getting the result as:

```
Date[CR]
```

I am using Expresso to test out my regular expressions. I am pretty new with using regex so I am not familiar with how to do things and stuff.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You need to enable single-line matching. Try adding a `(?s)` flag in front.

Comment: Not sure if expresso supports non-fixed length lookbehinds. I know that very few engines supports it. Also, try to use `(?s)`, this should match newlines with `.`. Which means try the following: `(?s)(?i)date.*?\d+-\d+-\d+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a lookbehind assertion in this case, also unlimited length lookbehinds are (I think) only supported by .net.

I would use a capturing group instead:

```
(?is)date.*?(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})
```

You will find the date in the first capturing group.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?35cbg)

`(?is)` is enabling the case independent matching mode `i` and the single line mode `s`, that makes the `.` also match newline characters.

`.*?` is matching lazily any characters.

`(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})` matches one or two digits, a dash, one or two digits, a dash, then 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this regex:

```
(?i)(?<=Date)[\S\s]*?(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))
```

In your regex you are also missing a `-` before last `\d+`. Also this regex will handle the `year` part with four digits as well as two digits.